# Position in Window of given item in GridView without using touch/click events

Tags: android, gridview

There is this method that returns the location of the view on screen

```
int[] coordinates = new int[2];
view.getLocationInWindow(coordinates);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow(int[])

I want to know if it is possible to get/calculate the coordinates for any element on a gridview given its position without using touch/click events.

Something like

```
gridview.getLocationInWindowForPosition(position, coordinates);
```

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Can't you simply use `gridview.getChildAt(position - gridview.getFirstVisiblePosition()).getLocationInWindow(coordinates)`?

Comment: that led me to something I could use, thank you!